# view my raspi camera on a monitor plugged into one of the two onboard hdmi ports

Tags: camera

I want to view my raspi camera on a monitor plugged into one of the two onboard hdmi ports. I can't find any info on how to achieve
that.

Comment: Here is an example in Python using the picamera2 library: https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2/blob/main/examples/preview.py

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no evidence of any research.